# What's the verb that describes "the act of using your hand to illustrate your words"?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-usage

Example:

> He extended his arm, [...] water rushing out.

At first I thought about *imitating*, but it doesn't sound right to me (I could be wrong, though). Then I tried *simulate*, however, a simulation is different from an illustration.

What's the right verb to use in these situations? Mimicking?

Comment: Gesticulate.   :)

Comment: Gesticulate is a good response for the question's title, but *imitating* would be fine for the context described in the body.

Comment: Why is "gesturing" not an answer?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To [gesticulate](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/gesticulate) can be used to refer to that specific action:

> - To make gestures especially while speaking, as for emphasis.

(AHD)

> - to make or use gestures, esp. in an animated or excited manner with or instead of speech.

(Random House Kernerman Webster's College)

- Whenever she wished for anything very much she would gesticulate in a very expressive manner.

In your specific case ***[to pantomime](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/pantomime)***  can be used:

> - To represent or express by pantomime: *pantomime a story on the stage; pantomimed "baby" by cradling an imaginary infant.*

- He extended his arms and pantomimed (the action of )  water rushing out. 
  (Also ***mimic*** would fit in the contex).

Comment: +1 for *pantomime*, which to me is so idiomatic in the OP's example sentence that I'm tempted to say it's the unique right answer.

Comment: Or of course just "mime" ("miming" in the questioner's context).

Comment: It should be "mime."  Pantomime includes facial gestures.

Comment: "Mime" is correct.

Answer (score 1):

It's not right for the context you've used, but I've seen people being referred to as a "**hand-talker**" when they excessively wave or gesticulate (with their hands) while speaking.

http://www.today.com/health/why-you-cant-stop-talking-your-hands-6C10526377